# Substituting JSON null values in Mantle

Tags: ios, json, github-mantle

I'm using Mantle to parse some JSON which normally looks like this:

```
"fields": {

      "foobar": 41
    }
```

However sometimes the value of foobar is null:

```
"fields": {

      "foobar": null
    }
```

This causes `MTLValidateAndSetValue` to throw an exception as it's trying to set a nil value via Key-Value Coding.

What I would like to do is detect the presence of this null value and substitute it with -1.

I tried overriding `foobarJSONTransformer` in my `MTLModel` subclass as follows:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)foobarJSONTransformer {
return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^id(id inObj) {
    if (inObj == [NSNull null]) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger: -1];
    } else {
        return inObj;
    }
}];
```

...and I can see this code being called but inObj is never equal to `[NSNull null]`, hence the substitution doesn't happen and the exception is still thrown by Mantle.

What is the correct way to catch this JSON null case and do the substitution?

Answer (score 7):

I had incorrectly assumed `NSNull` would be generated for a null JSON value. In fact it is parsed to a `nil` value.

So the solution is to check `inObj` against `nil`, rather than `NSNull`:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)foobarJSONTransformer {
return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^id(id inObj) {
    if (inObj == nil) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger: -1];
    } else {
        return inObj;
    }
}];
```

the substitution will then work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

If you received as `null`, it will generated as `NSNull`. But if they `missed` this field or send it as `empty`, it will generate as `nil` while parsing. so better you can use below code

```
if (inObj == nil || inObj == [NSNull null] )
```

Answer (score 1):

create a base model and inherit MTLModel,and override blow code:

```
- (void)setNilValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    [self setValue:@0 forKey:key];
}
```

if you property is oc object,it will be nil immediate,and can't execute the method.but it can execute if the property is int,bool or float.